# innrhtml.indexof(FieldName) does not work properly, read only 4 to 5 letters of field name

Tags: javascript, html, search, tags, innerhtml

```
function findacontrol(FieldName) {

var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
// get all comments
for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ )
{
 // now match the field name
 if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(FieldName) > 0)
  {         
   return arr[i];
  }
}
}
```

If there are two cloumns DepartmentName and Department and if we try to match Department column than this function returns DepartmentName instead of Department, it does not match the full column name. what can be the issue?

Comment: I don't see where this could be useful. Just curious: why?

Comment: i want to add the HyperLink according to the column name selected on the NewForm.aspx. just help me to search the column name. it is referring only partial column name

Answer (score 0):

It is because `indexOf` finds the word *Department* in the column name *DepartmentName*, you should use `==` operator to exactly match the two strings:

```
/* Leading and trailing white-space regular expressions */
var ls = /^\s*/;
var ts = /\s*$/;

function findControl(FieldName) {
    // Get all columns
    var cols = document.getElementsByTagName("th");

    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++){
        // Trim column name before matching
        if (cols[i].innerHTML.replace(ls, "").replace(ts, "") == FieldName){         
            return cols[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great demo.. very nice site. Thanks but if i enter DepartmentName than too it returns Department. i got the alternate solution i have retrieved the whole innerHtml and used .split('\"')[1] and i got required column name every time. Thank you so much for helping Coder